# Derivatives with functions of two or more variables

Tags: derivatives

For the function $ln(4x^2+4y^2)$ when taking the derivative with respect to $x$, do you essentially leave the $y$ terms alone? I received the answer  of $\frac{2x+y^2}{x^2+y^2}$, however the books solution deems that to be wrong. Looking for some insight on what I'm doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you "ignore" the $y$ terms just as you would constant terms.  Note that this also means if there are any terms with **only** $y$ in them (no $x$'s), then after you take the derivative, those terms disappear just as constant terms do.

When you differentiate $4x^{2} + 5$, for example, you get $8x$ because the constant $5$ disappears.

Similarly, when you differentiate $\ln{(4x^{2} + 4y^{2})}$, you should get:

$\dfrac{1}{4x^{2} + 4y^{2}}(8x)$.  This is because when you apply the chain rule and differentiate $4x^{2} + 4y^{2}$, remember that you are treating any $y$'s as constants.  So the derivative of $4x^{2} + 4y^{2}$ should be identical to the derivative of $4x^{2} + 5$.  In the latter, the $5$ goes away since it is a constant.  Therefore, in the former the $4y^{2}$ should also go away because it is a constant.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Much appreciated!

Comment: @user153509 You're welcome!